# display info in view from scheduler

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have scheduled task what works every 5 min. Sometimes this task changes variable (I tried global, gon etc) and I would like to display this changing in browser.
Ideally this task should be in config/initializer but I tried locate it in controller and even as nested function in controller/action.
I checked the var was changed (print in console) but any attempts to display this change (using flash, javascript) was failed: was displaied only original value. I even know why: the corresponding view doesn’t see changing before action finished in the case of nested in action task (but it never finishs due scheduling job) and just no corresponding view in other locations.
It means I use wrong way due to probably my wrong understanding of mvc but still can’t find correct way.
Any ideas how display info in view from scheduler? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you display the change from within the function that changes the variables? That way it knows which variables were changed without having to go through every possible variable.

Comment: Where? In which view? Can you please show the simplest example of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given very little information.  It sounds like you want real time updates to a web page.  Rails has something for that:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: I repeated example from this tutorial. May be it will work but currently I have [ActionCable] Broadcasting to web_notifications:1: {:title=>"New things!", :body=>120} where 120 is value of changed var. Only it is still in console - nothing on the view.